# Solving a system of equations using Laplace transforms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, laplace-transform

**Problem:**
I want to use Laplace transforms to solve the following:
$$\def\b{\begin{pmatrix}}\def\e{\end{pmatrix}}\def\d{\dot}$$
$$ \b\d y_1 \\ \d y_2\e = \b  2y_1 + y_2 \\ -y_1 \e$$

where $y_1(0)=0$ and $y_2(0)=1$

---

Firstly I would like to say: I have never done a question like this. Secondly I am following what would appear to be a very badly explained method in my Kreyszig - Advanced Engineering Mathematics textbook(which is actually usually clear and pleasna

---

**My attempt:** We convert everything into the form the textbook uses:
$$A= \b 2 & 1\\-1 & 0\e,G=\b0\\0\e,Y=\mathfrak{L}(y)$$
We jump straight into the form: $$(A-sI)Y = -y(0) - G$$
$$\b 2-s & 1\\-1 & -s\e\b Y_1 \\ Y_2\e=\b0\\-1\e$$
$$(2-s)Y_1 + Y_2 = 0$$
$$-Y_1-sY_2 + 1=0$$
$$Y_2=\frac{1-Y_1}s$$
$$(2-s)Y_1 + \frac{1-Y_1}s = 0$$
$$Y_1+\frac{1-Y_1}{s(2-s)}=0$$
$$\frac{(1-s)Y_1}{(2-s)}=0$$
$$(1-s)Y_1=0$$
$$Y_1=sY_1$$

Now I don't know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$y_1' = 2y_1 + y_2 \\ y_2' = -y_1 \\ y_1(0) = 0, y_2(0) = 1$$

Taking Laplace transforms, we have:

$$sy_1(s) - y_1(0) = 2y_1(s) + y_2(s) \\ s y_2(s) - y_2(0) = -y_1(s)$$

Substituting ICs yields:

$$sy_1(s) = 2y_1(s) + y_2(s) \\ s y_2(s) - 1 =   -y_1(s)$$

You can put this into matrix form to solve if desired (but it is instructive to see where things went wrong). We would get:

$$\b s-2 & -1\\1 & s\e\b y_1 \\ y_2\e=\b0\\1\e$$

From the first equation, we have:

$$y_2(s) = (s-2)y_1(s)$$

Substituting that into the second equation and simplifying yields:

$$y_1(s) = \dfrac{1}{(s-1)^2}$$

The inverse Laplace yields:

$$y_1(t) = t e^t$$

I am sure you can take it from here.

You should end up with:

$$y_2(t) = -e^t(t-1)$$

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your detailed response, I am just processing it now :).

Comment: So simple, sad I didn't know about the $f'(t) = sF(s) - f(0)$!

Comment: Yes of course, thank you very much for your help once again @Amzoti!